# loading gif inside asp gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp: GridView which retrieves some data from a database. Based on one of the columns. If the item in the column has a specific value such as "processing" then a loading gif should appear in the next column. if the value is "successful" then no gif to appear, and it should just be blank space?

Any ideas would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually I place a TemplateField when I have some little more than simple data show. I place on **GridView** that two fields

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="cStatus" ... />

<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="cStatus" ... >
    <ItemTemplate ><%#GetStatusIcon(Container.DataItem)%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on code behind the function that return the image that I like to show as:

```
protected string GetStatusIcon(object oItem)
{
    // a sample how to get your value. Change the type to yours one (eg string)
    bool fStatus = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "cStatus");

    if (fStatus)
        return "<img src=\"one.gif\" />";
    else
        return "<img src=\"other.gif\" />";
}
```

Comment: i am not using objects from classes. how would this work with strings

Comment: where do you see objects here ? Just copy paste it... if you do not understand what I do here... then... I dont know how to transfer it to you